# cursive letters inside equation

Tags: fonts, math-mode, italic

I want to use cursive font inside an equation. I have defined a macro

```
\newenvironment{frcseries}{\fontfamily{frc}\selectfont}{}
\newcommand{\textfrc}[1]{{\frcseries#1}}
```

With this I get cursive fonts outside equation only. Could anyone please tell me how can I get cursive font inside equation? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition is not really the best even for text:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\frcshape}{\fontfamily{frc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfrc}{\frcshape}
```

Then `\textfrc` will be much safer.

For having it also in math mode, define

```
\newcommand{\mathfrc}[1]{\mbox{\frcshape #1}}
```

and so

```
$\mathfrc{Abc}$
```

would give the expected result (which, in my opinion, is quite bad).

Note. *Don't* use `\textfrc` in math mode if you load `amsmath`, because it would try loading font sizes that aren't available.