# How to write cursive i (or iota) in latex?

Tags: symbols

How can I write the following symbol? I tried but I couldn't find any source...I am looking for cursive i

[image]

Comment: Check this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84619/cursive-letters-inside-equation as I think this is a duplicate question

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, this is `\iota`, not an ordinary undotted "*i*".

Comment: $`\imath`$ perhaps?